# Closest number to n that is a factor of m

Tags: algorithm, math

So I'm looking for an algorithm able to give me the closest number to n that is a factor of m.

In case I'm wording this question stupid  I'm going to provide some examples :)

n = 10; m = 400; output: 10

n = 11; m = 400; output: 10

n = 16; m = 400; output: 16

n = 17; m = 400; output 16

n = 19; m = 400; output 20

I'm feeling stupid right now. I could just brute force this with some loops i guess but that doesn't feel right. I'm currently doing this in python but if i knew the formula i guess it doesn't matter what language i use.

Edit: So i build it with a while loop in javascript and it's working but i would still want a more elegant solution.

```
export const closestNumber = (n, m) => {
  if (m % n !== 0) {
    let p = 0;
    while (true) {
      p += 1;
      if (m % (n + p) === 0) {
        return Math.abs(n + p);
      }
      if (m % (n - p) === 0) {
        return Math.abs(n - p);
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.abs(n);
};
```

Thanks in advance guys and girls. I know there is a lot of smart people here. :)

Comment: Please provide what have you done to solve your problem

Comment: Find dividers of `m`, sort them, and lower_bound/binary_search `n` and check the 2 candidates ?

Comment: Which is the range of value of `m`?

Comment: pick closest between n - (n % m) and n + (m - (n % m))

Comment: How is this too broad?

Comment: A better title might be "Closest number to n that is a factor of m"

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm sorry. I'll edit the post.

Comment: In the worst case, you'll have to factorize `m`. I'm sure you can find algorithms to do this (but it won't be fast for very large `m`). If you find a way to do this quickly without factorizing `m` first, then you'll have broken most of the internet's encryption :)

Comment: So my loop solution is not good enough for you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to find out every factors of the number and compare the number to each factors.

The shorter way to find every factors is :

```
// find each factors
    var i=2;
    var diviseurs=[1];
    for(var d=1;d<Math.sqrt(n)+1;d++)
        for(var mult=d;mult<n;mult++)
            if(d*mult == n){
                if(d==mult){
                    diviseurs.push(d);
                }else{
                    diviseurs.push(d);
                    diviseurs.push(mult);
                }
        }
    diviseurs.push(n);
```

You find each first prime factors until sqrt(number) (because they are no more after that) 
and you add to the list of factors, every prime factor multiple to the number.

We also can compare while we find factors. I can improve that if you want.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function closestNum(){
 var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
 var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

 // find each factors
 var i = 2;
 var diviseurs = [1];
 for( var d=1; d < Math.sqrt(n)+1 ; d++){
  for(var mult = d; mult < n; mult++)
   if(d*mult == n){
    if(d == mult){
     diviseurs.push(d);
    }else{
     diviseurs.push(d);
     diviseurs.push(mult);
    }
  }
 }
 diviseurs.push(n);


 // find closest
 var closest = diviseurs[0];
 var diff = Math.abs (m - closest);
 for (var val = 0; val < diviseurs.length; val++) {
  var newdiff = Math.abs(m - diviseurs[val]);
  if (newdiff < diff) {
   diff = newdiff;
   closest = diviseurs[val];
  }
 }

 console.log("diviseurs :",diviseurs);
 console.log("closest :",closest);
 document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = closest;
}

</script>

<body onload="closestNum()" lang="fr-FR">

<span>number</span><br/>
<input type="number" value="400" id="num1"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>closest from :</span><br/>
<input type="number" value="19" id="num2"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>closest factor :</span><br/>
<span id ="res"></span>

<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="closestNum()">run</button>

</body>
</html>
```